# tradingview link in same page largeChartUrl:

Tags: jquery, charts, tradingview-api

graph when click will new tab / "_blank" , c
can i make  "largeChartUrl" link to "same page" / "_parent" not new tab ?

```
  "title": "Indices",
  "width": 770,
  "height": 450,
  "locale": "en",
  "showSymbolLogo": true,
  "largeChartUrl" : "http://localhost/jk.php"
```

Comment: TradingView widgets do not offer this functionality.

Comment: thank you Rory.. its iframe results when using widget... i ll make graph self with API data.. so can make anything..thank you so much